# 2018 Crosstrek making a bottoming out thumb noise in DF assembly when going over very small things

Tags: subaru, suspension

I just got Subaru 2018 Crosstrek Premium a week ago and traveled a couple minor dirt roads. In my drivers side axle wheel area I am getting a loud thump that sounds like bottoming out, it is loud and startling, look a rubber or wood mallet hitting something or maybe like a large thing being kicked up and hitting the vehicle. It happens when going over with the drivers side front tire very small rocks that stick up out of the road not very very far in the 2-3 inch range or well within the travel of the suspension. The rocks ar not coming loose to hit anything. It is only on the driver front assembly. It does not happen when going over dips or things. the vehicle drives fine, no pull, no noises other then this. No warning lights.

A visual inspection climbing under the vehicle reveals nothing. No bad bushings, no unusual wear points or anything that seems detached or loose. My best guess is that it is in the strut. I am taking it to the dealer to have them look at it and hopefully repair it. My feeling is that they may be clueless. I am hoping that someone else has had this problem and been able to remedy, so that I can go into the dealer with some kind of clue what it may be.

So Subaru owners have you had a similar clunking sound on your vehicle? If so what was the problem?

Comment: Being a 2018 model, it may still be under Subaru Factory Warranty.  If so, you should take it to the dealer and get it checked out.

Comment: @jwh20 Yes it of course is I was just looking for some feedback on the problem so I am better equipped when I do go into the dealer. I went yesterday, and they said were going to order a strut and give you a call when it comes in in a day or two.

Comment: You'll know a bad strut if the side of car over the bad strut dips deep when you suddenly brake.

Comment: You write "a loud thumb." Do you mean a loud "thump?"

Comment: General rule is that struts are replaced in pairs; if they try to get away with replacing just one on a two year old car, have a word with the service manager.